# Want to redirect TLD domain to a subdomain on https with htaccess. Tried htaccess RewriteRule Redirect found but not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect via .htaccess directives all these:

htt**p**://domain.com AND www.domain.com AND htt**p**://**subdomain**.domain.com

TO :

http**s**://**subdomain**.domain.com

Please note that "subdomain" is an unique subdomain, I do not want to redirect any subdomain but only one.

I'm not familiar with .htaccess directives so I tried all RewriteRule or Redirect snippet found here or elsewere, but it's not working. I must miss something.

EDIT: I added a .htaccess into sur directory of subdomain with this and it works now:
It's OK, I added this in htaccess into the subdirectory of subdomain :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
# for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Before you try, clear your cache, or use another browser.

Comment: I tried (after cache cleaning and with two browser to be sure) it redirect htt**p**://domain.com and htt**p**://www.domain.com to http**s**://subdomain.domain.com but do not redirect htt**p**://subdomain.domain.com to http**s**://subdomain.domain.com. I have another .htaccess in subdomain folder - for url formatting, maybe it's blocking redirect ?

Comment: Content of .htacess into subdomain folder is : `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: It's OK, I added this in htaccess into the subdirectory of subdomain : `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` It works now.